# How to display integer to string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two table which is table1 and table2.

IN table1

```
Id Country     
------------
1   India     
2   USA     
3   PAK
4   AUS
5   Newzealand 
Many more
```

IN table2

```
U_id Country_id     
------------
1     3
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     1
many more
```

I need output like

```
U_id Country_id     
------------
1     PAK
2     India     
3     USA     
4     PAK
5     India  
many more
```

I tried join query

```
SELECT table1.country, table2.Country_id FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.Id = table2.U_id
```

Can you help me without CASE?

Comment: Any basic introductory book or tutorial would be able to address this.

Comment: Mr.Strawberry, Can you share the link?

Comment: Sure: google.com

Comment: Mr.Strawberry, That's the reason I upload question here.

Comment: What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select b.U_id, a.Country as Country_id from table1 as a left join table2 as b on a.ID = b.U_id
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Vin, It is working but I am not getting all the records. I have more than 500 records in my table and I am getting only 70 records

Comment: The reason is, In the table 1 have 70 records.

Answer (score 0):

you can try left join

```
table1 --> Id | Country 
table2 --> U_id | Country_id
```

update this query

```
SELECT table2.U_id, table1.Country FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 WHERE table2.Country_id = table1.Id
```

I hope this will work

Answer (score -1):

You must change your query:

```
SELECT table2.U_id, table1.Country 
FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.Id = table2.U_id
```